# Insert rows in table without affecting AUTO_INCREMENT in MariaDB

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb, dml

I have a table with a bunch of rows whose ID's are numbers with value less than 20,000,000. The table structure looks like this:

```sql
CREATE TABLE records(
    id int(11) not null AUTO_INCREMENT,
    ... more data columns ...
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=16432352 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

A system that is out of my control inserts rows in this table and the database insert those records with a generated ID.

But, I need to insert records in this table with very big ID's (starting 50,000,000). Also, it's important to note that the uncontrolled system inserts few records, such that the records I'm going to insert never collides with the records of the uncontrolled system.

Making some tests I realized that when I insert a record with a very vig ID, the AUTO_INCREMENT value jumps to that very big ID. For example:

First, I check the initial_auto_increment value:

```sql
SHOW TABLE STATUS FROM my-database like 'records';
```

... the auto_increment value looks like this:

```
#    Name, ... , Auto_increment, ...
 'record', ... ,    '16432352', ...
```

Next, I insert the record with a very big ID.

```sql
INSERT INTO records (id, ...) VALUES(679456755, ...);
```

Then, checking again the auto_increment value:

```sql
SHOW TABLE STATUS FROM my-database like 'records';
```

.. the final result look like this:

```
#    Name, ... , Auto_increment, ...
 'record', ... ,    '679456756', ...
```

My question is: How can I temporarily disable the AUTO_ICREMENT feature in such way that my records with very big ID's don't mess around with the AUTO_INCREMENT value of the table?

PS. I'm using MariaDB 10.

Edit: I changed the numbers, but the question is the same.

Comment: Did you consider not using `AUTO_INCREMENT`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL and MariaDB actually enforce the restriction AUTO_INCREMENT > MAX(id)

See [ALTER TABLE Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/alter-table.html)

> You cannot reset the counter to a value less than or equal to the value that is currently in use. For both InnoDB and MyISAM, if the value is less than or equal to the maximum value currently in the AUTO_INCREMENT column, the value is reset to the current maximum AUTO_INCREMENT column value plus one.

You can use ALTER TABLE to set the AUTO_INCREMENT to any value higher than MAX(id) if you would like to store higher values, however you *cannot* set it to a lower value than one of the rows currently in the table.

If you need to create rows in a "gap", with lower IDs than the AUTO_INCREMENT value, you would need to explicitly specify the id value in your INSERT. But if a process beyond your control is inserting rows and not specifying the IDs then they are always going to obtain IDs higher than everything else currently in the table.

The only thing I can suggest, if you are able to adjust what IDs are used for what, is that you reserve low IDs for your purposes (so use, say, 1 to 10,000 instead of 50,000,000 to 50,009,999), set the AUTO_INCREMENT to 10,001 and then let the outside process use the higher IDs - this would work just fine provided you don't run out of space.

For a longer term solution, consider switching to [UUIDs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier) - though you would need to modify the process that is outside your control for this.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the `AUTO_INCREMENT` to any value you please:

```
ALTER TABLE records AUTO_INCREMENT = ?
```

Though I'd strongly recommend burying records at high ID numbers. Usually lower is better, or just mixing them in with regular records. Being obsessive about these things leads to conflict later on when your assumptions end up being mistaken.

Comment: I tried doing the ALTER TABLE ... after inserting the record with the very big ID, but it doesn't change the value. BTW, thanks for your answer

Comment: It used to be the case that the `AUTO_INCREMENT` setting would reset to `MAX(id)` under certain circumstances so you may be fighting an uphill battle here. That's why I'd recommend never forcing it too far.